# Cannot catch PDOException in laravel 3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-3

I'm trying to catch a PDOException in laravel 3 but it seems as if I cannot do this.  My code is as follows:

```
try{
    DB::connection()->pdo->beginTransaction();

    Myobject::create($cleaned_input_array);

    // do other stuff that could possibly throw a custom exception

    DB::connection()->pdo->commit();
}
catch(\PDOException $e)
{
    DB::connection()->pdo->rollBack();
    return HTTP_STATUS::response(BAD_REQUEST, array("error creating");
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    DB::connection()->pdo->rollBack();
    return HTTP_STATUS::response(BAD_REQUEST, array($e->getMessage()));
}
```

The general exception is caught if the other parts in the 'try' throw an exception.  If they do not, everything runs clean.  If the `create` has an issue executing the MYSQL statement it does not throw a PDOException, it is only throwing a general Exception.

Comment: why is there a \ in front of your `PDOException`

Comment: I've read you can place a '\' in front of PDOException for namespace issues.  Even if I remove the '\' I still am unable to catch a PDOException.  I should note that the error on the create is being thrown as a general exception...

Comment: Why not dump out the type of `$e`, eg `get_class($e)`? That will at least tell you the type of exception being caught in the general exception handler

Comment: Please expand `Myobject` which seems to be relevant (you expect it to throw a PDOException!) so that people can easily reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please remove the first catch block and var_dump the generic Exception that you are supposed to get when PDOException is thrown...

Comment: Without knowing what the DB class is `throw`ing, there's no way to answer this.

Answer (score -1):

A model wouldn't actually throw `PDOException`, that would be caught internally and a `\Illuminate\Database\QueryException` would be thrown instead, try catching that.

Comment: That is not being caught either.  To be clear, I simply replaced `\PDOException` with `QueryException` in the above code and the regular `Exception` is all that is being caught.

Comment: If your code is namespaced you'll need to provide  the fully qualified namespace, otherwise it'll never be caught.

Comment: My code is not name spaced, I was merely copying the example which showed the example.  I only have one instance of that class/method.  Thus, the question still remains...

Comment: Wouldn't it be `catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $queryException)` in the global namespace (which OP is apparently in)? That being said, `QueryException` extends `PDOException` anyway

Comment: Yeah, either way, I'm pretty sure it needs to be the full namespace, exceptions are a bit funny tbh. @WildBill just for arguments sake, try removing the `Exception` catch.

Comment: `Illuminate` has nothing to do with Laravel 3!